# Unable to connect UART/USART2 in STM32F407ZG

Tags: c, arm, uart, stm32f4, cortex-m4

When I try to connect to PC using UART/USART2 on platform STM32F407ZG is not working, Here is the following code which I used,

```
char uart_rd;
void main() 
{
    // Initialize UART module at 1200 bps
    UART2_Init_Advanced (1200, _UART_8_BIT_DATA, _UART_NOPARITY, _UART_ONE_STOPBIT, &_GPIO_MODULE_USART2_PD56);
    Delay_ms(100);                  // Wait for UART module to stabilize
    UART2_Write_Text("Start");
    UART2_Write(13);
    UART2_Write(10);
    while (1) 
    {                     // Endless loop
        if (UART2_Data_Ready()) 
        {     // If data is received
           uart_rd = UART2_Read();     // read the received data
           UART2_Write(uart_rd);       // and send data via UART
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you configure the pins involved?  Did you wire an RS232 inverting level shifter or a USB-serial converter to those pins?

Comment: Configuring the clocks could be helpful too. We have no idea which board you use, so any help is limited at best.

Answer (score 1):

As with any cortex m peripheral, you need to turn on the clock

Comment: yes, I agree with you, the same code by changing the PORT, I used in STM32F107VC and it was working fine

Comment: Post the smallest complete code that replicates the problem.  Don't make us guess about all you initializations.